# How to append page url to link in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, hyperlink

How do I add a link to a page in wordpress and it automatically appends the page url to it dynamically?

I basically want to add a link example [www.link.com](http://www.link.com)  and when i add the link to any page it will automatically append the page url to it so it looks like this  [www.link.com/my-page-title](http://www.link.com/my-page-title) to the reader.

Thanks
Red

Comment: are you trying to have a link to a page on an external site that has the same name as the current page on the current site?

Comment: Im trying to link to an external site that leads to the external sites search page and appends my url page keywords/title.  
Example,  my url page is  www.website.com/blue-ball   and my affiliate link on that page should look like this  www.affiliate.com/search?query=blue+ball
Basically the link on my page  appends my url page title to the affiliate link.
So no matter on what page I paste the affiliate link it will always append my url page title/keywords.